# Adding an action bar in other activities than activity_main

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I am developing a simple app which has a few activities. So when I start the app and get to my MainActivity I have my action bar and everything is great. There are 2 buttons in that MainActivity which when clicked take you to other activities. What I want to do is I want to implement an action bar to those secondary activities. I have tried everything I could find on google or youtube and nothing worked. Hope you guys can help me. I wish to put on that action bar the BACK button which will take me back to activity_main but of course I need an action bar first. I will give you the code for one of my secondary activities so that you could advise me what to add.

**Newton Activity**

```
public class NewtonScreen extends Activity
{
     private Button theAnswerButton, theHintButton, theSuckButton;

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.newton_layout);

     theAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button);
     theHintButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hint_button);
     theSuckButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.suck_at_physics_button);


}

/**@Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.newton_menu, menu);
          return true;
}

@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
     int id = item.getItemId();

     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
    }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}**/

// Some other methods that are not important for this issue
```

As you can see I have tried to put these 2 Override methods and I have even created a newton_menu layout but it seems it does not work.

**Newton menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".NewtonScreen">

<item 
    android:id="@+id/newton_action_exit"
    android:title="@string/action_exit"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change **extends Activity** to **extend AppCompatActivity**

call this code in oncreate

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and this code

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
     int itemId = item.getItemId();
     if(itemId == android.R.id.home){
         finish();
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: When I typed this code getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); It gives me an error java.lang.NullPointerException and the Override methods gives an error that it is not overriding any methods from the superclass :/

Answer (score 1):

> I think your project or your second class not support actionbar.You should change it in style.xml file and make sure second class apply it.
>    Example style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Adding : You extend class with ActionBarActivity or AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend all your activities with Mainactivity(which can be considered as base activity having the actionbar).

eg:Let your MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

and let other Activities extend with MainActivity like

SecondActivity extends MainActivity.

Hope this will solve your problem.